# Access an arbitrary controller from inside an Ember.Object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, coffeescript, ember-data

I have been struggling with the following case:

1. I have created a singleton session object (extends Ember.Object) which takes care of session management. It is injected into every controller so it can be accessed. For the sake of this question it could be an arbitrary Ember.Object.
2. I have a user model and a user adapter which extends the fixture adapter. Fixtures have been loaded. It also has an user controller derived from arrayController. It works fine,... if I load it as a model in a route, I can display the data in the template via #each.

My question is now, can I access the this user controller/model in my Ember.Object, which has no view or routes associated with it?

In Emberscript (Coffeescript) I want to do something like this:

```
class App.MyObject extends Ember.Object
  arbitraryFunction: ->
    email = <getUserWithID(x)>.email
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can wrap your object into another `controller` and use `needs` to access desire controller's property.

Comment: In App.ready I now use @inject('myobject', 'store', 'store:main'). This injects the store inside the "store" field ob my object instance. This way I can use this.store or @store in any method inside the object.